# Importing files in node package without including dist folder name

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I have following directory structure for a library which will be imported by other node js project.

```
my-lib/
├─ dist/
│  ├─ index.js
│  ├─ foo.js
├─ src/
│  ├─ index.ts
│  ├─ foo.ts
├─ package.json
```

I have following package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js"
}
```

I have specified `main` as `dist/index.js`, so if I understand correctly, members exported from index.ts (js) can be imported as `import abc from 'my-lib'`. If I have to access exported members from foo.ts (js) file then I might end up doing `import foo from 'my-lib/dist/foo'`. So here I have to specify the `dist` folder name in import path. Is there way to specify just `'my-lib/foo'` omitting `dist` folder name? (just like importing `dist/index.js` file.)

Answer (score 20):

This can be accomplished with [subpath exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_exports) in package.json.

```
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./foo": "./dist/foo.js"
  }
```

Comment: also support glob:   "exports": {
    "./*": "./dist/*.js"
  },

Comment: Doesn't this still have such incredibly limited support as to be unviable? E.g. requires tsconfig moduleResolution set to Node16+ which I have seen almost no where.

Comment: Strangely it does't work for me, even though I do this already. It works when running in dev mode, but tsc compiler complains when making production build. super annoying

Answer (score 4):

As explained in node.js documentation, it is possible to add subpath exports. Check it out [here](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_exports).

In your case it should look similar to following

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./foo": "./dist/foo.js"
  }
}
```

After exporting like this you can import as follows

```
import foo from 'my-lib/foo'
```